# ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback not working on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

Before our application is deployed to our production environment, we call a number APIs in lower environments from our .NET web application. Those servers that host the APIs tend not to have certs signed by a trusted Certificate Authority.

I created the following code as a workaround, with a safety to exclude running this code in our production environment:

```
if (ignoreCertErrors && environmentName.ToLower() != "PROD")
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
}
```

Both ignoreCertErrors and environmentName are parameters provided to the method that contains this logic.

This worked on my local development box (Windows 7) but when I deployed it to Windows 2012 R2 test server, my calls to APIs with certs that aren't trusted still fail with the following errors:

> ================================================================= 
>   Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a send. Stack Trace:
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResultar)
>
> ================================================================= 
>   Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Stack
>   Trace:
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> ================================================================= 
>   Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   Stack Trace:
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> =================================================================

Do I need change this logic, or do something new to ignore certificate warnings on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but did you mean environmentName.ToUpper() != "PROD"?

Comment: That is a good catch, we hadn't gone to production yet. That doesn't solve the problem because in either case it would still be true, so the code would execute.

Comment: Has the server SSL3 enabled or disabled? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3009008.aspx . https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/iis-disabling-ssl-v3.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to approach this a different way, I've created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599690/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-api-endpoint-call-fails) related to the error messages and ask for suggestions to resolve.